# No output when running Python 3 in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, output, python-3.8

I'm using Python 3.8 on VScode, but I can't seem to get the program to write anything in output, even with simple commands like: print("Hello world!"). It shows up in the terminal well enough, so the code shouldn't be the problem. Do i need to fix anything in the setting to make it show the output?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwNDR.png): Picture of terminal:

Answer (score 0):

Please could you check your user settings.json and workspace settings.json for the existence of a setting for terminal.integrated.shell.*.
I believe you may have changed the shell to use command prompt instead of powershell.

Also, please could you provide some screenshots of the terminal
And any errors logged in the console widows (go to Help->Toggle Developer Tools)

Comment: Thanks. I added the picture. You might be right about the shell, but i can't really find anywhere i can choose between command prompt and powershell. 
is it one of these 4 settings? :  - Terminal › Integrated › Shell: Linux, 
- Terminal › Integrated › Shell: Windows, -  Terminal › Integrated › Shell: Osx, - Terminal › Integrated › Shell Args: Windows